# What's the best way to tidy up a PHP array with both indexed entries and associative entries?

Tags: php, array

I have two closely related questions:

1) I have a mixed PHP array. Not mixed in that it contains strings, floats, booleans etc. but mixed in that it is a hybrid indexed / associative array. Most of its entries look like they are from an indexed array while the very last entry looks like it's from an associative array:

```
$myFruit = [
  'apple',
  'banana',
  'cherry',
  'Other_Fruit' => ['Damson', 'Elderberry', 'Fig', 'Grapefruit']
];
```

It strikes me that this is a **bad idea**, but I need to confirm that first... Is it a bad idea to have an array in PHP which is a hybrid between an indexed array and an associative array? Or is this not entirely uncommon practice in PHP?

2) If it ***is*** a bad idea (as I suspect), what is the best way to tidy it up, given that I want to preserve the entry `['Other_Fruit']` exactly as it is.

At present I am using the following:

---

### Code to Review:

```
$myFruit2 = [];
$myFruit2['Fruitbowl'] = $myFruit;
$myFruit2['Other_Fruit'] = $myFruit2['Fruitbowl']['Other_Fruit'];
unset($myFruit2['Fruitbowl']['Other_Fruit']);
$myFruit = $myFruit2;
```

---

This leaves me with:

```
$myFruit = [
  'Fruitbowl' => ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
  'Other_Fruit' => ['Damson', 'Elderberry', 'Fig', 'Grapefruit']
];
```

which is *exactly* what I want... only I'm not sure I'm getting there the most efficient / fastest / best practice way.

Ultimately, I am looking to maximise speed, efficiency and process optimisation and minimise garbage collection or other processes which might slow the operation down. I want to tidy up the array as quickly as possible. I am uncertain, for example, if there are any (much faster) native functions that I ought to be using instead.

*(Subsequent thought: Maybe I can achieve this via **destructuring**...?)*

---

**Addendum:**

If I understand correctly, some users are objecting to the fact that in my code to be reviewed (above), I have used example variable names above instead of the actual variable names I am using.

*I cannot comprehend the nature of this objection*, but nevertheless, in response to it, here is the example (again):

```
$myFruit2 = [];
$myFruit2['Fruitbowl'] = $myFruit;
$myFruit2['Other_Fruit'] = $myFruit2['Fruitbowl']['Other_Fruit'];
unset($myFruit2['Fruitbowl']['Other_Fruit']);
$myFruit = $myFruit2;
```

And here is the actual code:

```
$Codesheets = [];
$Codesheets['Static'] = $moduleBlock['Codesheets'];
$Codesheets['Dynamic'] = $moduleBlock['Static']['Dynamic'];
unset($Codesheets['Static']['Dynamic']);
$moduleBlock['Codesheets'] = $Codesheets;
```

It will be apparent that the example I gave above is a 1:1 representation of the actual code.

Comment: Reason off-topic: `Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.`  You have provided generic data and asking for general best practice.

Comment: How can anyone propose to accurately advise on "_maximise speed, efficiency and process optimisation and minimise garbage collection or other processes which might slow the operation down_" when you haven't shown realistic sample data nor how you intend to process it?

Comment: Providing clear sample data is one requirement here.  A missing requirement is how you intend to use the data.  The fact that you are satisfied by slepic's answer is not a factor in deciding if your question is on-topic.  How can anyone confidently advise on the best data structure if we don't know how it will be used.

Comment: This is where you are failing to understand my motivations. I am not here to put anyone down, I am here to help CodeReview up.  Data structures are best designed by considering how the data will be used.  You are taking offense to my feedback, but what you should do is pay attention to what I am asking for and improve your question by telling us all the ways you intend to use the data.

Comment: Additionally, tell us where this data is coming from.  I assume that you are not hardcoding all this data, since you are favoring `unset()` in your answer.  Why is the data initially structured the way that it is? We should probably inform you about how to handle the data when it is declared at the very earliest point.

Comment: _"You are taking offense to my feedback."_ No, I am communicating to you that it looks like you are more concerned with referee-ing the question than trying to answer it. And yet several others have already endeavoured to answer the question and one of those answers has been accepted. So, it might be worth contemplating if the question is in need of being refereed? We can see that the question has now been shut down. If it had been shut down before being answered, so that it had neither answers nor an accepted answer, would that make this document more useful either to myself or anyone else?

Comment: I've reviewed enough code to know that `foo`/`bar` and other bogus-names "my real code is just like it", never, never, never ends well. Reviewers aren't here to answer specific questions about best practices illustrated with sample code, they're here to review *real*, working code with a purpose, and tell you if best practices are taking a beating. The difference, is that in that latter scenario, the code to be reviewed becomes *central*, not just an illustration of a situation encountered in code that needs an "answer" - CR doesn't do "answers", we do *reviews*.

Comment: I cannot post an answer until the question is reopened and I cannot vote to reopen without knowing 1. What is producing these arrays to be begin with (can they be improved)? and 2. How do you intend to use the data going forward?  Are you making a `<select>`? two `<select>`'s? are you using it as a lookup / validator / white/black list?  In the absence of all of this completely relevant information, I could only _guess_ would be most appropriate for your project.

Comment: I think we must be coming at this from different angles @mickmackusa (hence the initial conflict, which I am sorry for). Your position (if I understand it correctly) is that you need information which you currently don't have. My struggle is trying to understand what difference such information could possibly make. eg. In answer to your question: _"What is producing these arrays to begin with?"_ the answer is _"A function."_ I (genuinely) don't understand how this moves things along. Can I rewrite the function? Of course. Do I want to? No. Why not? Visual aesthetic / usability etc. [1/3]

Comment: Then, to be honest, I don't really understand some of the following questions: `<select>`, `lookup`, `validator`, `white/black list` - I don't understand what any of these are, so, initially, at least, I would say: _"No, I don't want to use the array for any of these, I just want a conventional array structure for future general purpose use."_ [2/3]

Comment: So, while you're asking me _"Where is the array coming from?"_ and _"Where is the array going?"_, I'm thinking: _"I don't care about any of that. I just want to ensure I'm building a robustly structured, future-proofed array."_ [3/3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often not very useful to have such a mix. It could make sense if you really wanted it to be associative array, but it just so happens that you can have the key strings contain numbers and even consecutive numers starting at zero which make it look like vector because php converts integer string keys to ints.

For example:

```
$robotsByName = [
  "0" => ["id" => 0, "name" => "0"],
  "1" => ["id" => 1, "name" => "1"],
  "2" => ["id" => 2, "name" => "2"],
  "johnny5" => ["id" => 3, "name" => "johnny5"],
];
```

If you have to deal with the input structure as is because it is not under your control, you could simplify your conversion like this:

```
$myFruit = [
  'Fruitbowl' => \array_slice($myFruit, 0, \count($myFruit)-1),
  'Other_Fruit' => $myFruit['Other_Fruit'],
];
```

Comment: `array_slice()` - perfect. Thank you. Also you've introduced me to _PHP Namespacing_.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here is denoting metadata about the fruit entries through the data structure. If it works for you then it’s certainly an acceptable solution. However, it will make the code much more readable and meaningful if you can get that metadata out of the structure and represent it directly. Someone unfamiliar with it (which might well be you a few months from now :)) is going to be able to figure out what everything means much more quickly.

To do that, you need to answer the question “what make fruit belong in the ‘other fruit’ array”? Making a guess based on the example data, is it a question of the ‘Other Fruit’ being less common?

If so, you could potentially use more meaningful names in your example last array.

```
$myFruit = [
 'common' => [
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'cherry',
 ],
'rare' => [
    'Damson',
    'Elderberry',
    'Fig',
    'Grapefruit',
 ],
];
```

A few notes in comparing this with what you have:

1. `array()` and `[]` do the exact same thing and are interchangeable. There is no reason to use `array()` at the very top level.
2. Doing `array([‘Fruitbowl’] => […])` make the key an array, which I don’t think you want. Rather, you likely want `array(‘Fruitbowl’=>[…])`, which is the same as `[‘fruitbowl’ => […]]`

All of this said, any multidimensional array is a good opportunity to think about writing a class to represent the data and incorporate an object. Something to keep in mind if any more complexity creeps into this array.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't make it sufficiently clear which part of my question was the Code to Review. I have edited the question to indicate it much more clearly. To restate my two questions: 1) Is a hybrid associative / indexed array a bad idea; and 2) what is the best approach to transform the former into a "non-mixed" associative (or even an indexed) array?

Answer (score -1):

Aha. Cracked it.

What I was looking for ultimately wasn't so much *destructuring*, but might be termed *"restructuring"*.

**Input:**

```
$myFruit = [
  'apple',
  'banana',
  'cherry',
  'Other_Fruit' => ['Damson', 'Elderberry', 'Fig', 'Grapefruit']
];
```

**Operation:**

```
$myFruit = [
  'Fruitbowl' => $myFruit,
  'Other_Fruit' => $myFruit['Other_Fruit']
];

unset($myFruit['Fruitbowl']['Other_Fruit']);
```

**Output:**

```
$myFruit = [
  'Fruitbowl' => ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
  'Other_Fruit' => ['Damson', 'Elderberry', 'Fig', 'Grapefruit']
];
```

Comment: I don't see this post as a _Review_.